# Polling / progress symfony messenger

Tags: php, symfony

TL;DR: how would one go about implement polling of progress of a batch job distributed across multiple workers when using Symfony Messenger? Or if this is a bad manner of going about it, what is a better tool or pattern to achieve what we want? (worker pool + polling of progress of multiple batches running at the same time, summarized per batch, every x amount of seconds/minutes)

While short-polling would be preferred (our application get's proxied/cached via Cloudflare which does not like long standing requests) I would welcome long-polling as well.

Backstory:

We have an system that does a lot of batch processing of products to and from our system. Now we use synchronous Symfony commands either manually via SSH or run via CronJobs, but this is not very scalable.

We wanted to switch to an event dispatcher of some kind and looking at Symfony Messenger it mostly fits the bill for scaling out our batching system. But I can not figure out how to implement polling to/for it, so both us and our customers have an indication of progress.

What we are looking at doing:

1. we or our customer starts batch job in our front-end, which get chunked and dispatched
2. workers start processing x amount of products
3. every 30 seconds or so we poll all workers regarding of how many items have been completed of x amount assigned for this specific batch job
4. front-end does some request every x seconds checking over-all progress.

Other then making a message for every item needed to be processed I can't think of a manageable way to achieve both scalability and polling, which would yield not much benefit over doing it synchronously. Is there some kind of pattern I should be looking at or a tool better fit to do this job?

Comment: Sorry, but this question is rather broad and thus opinion-based. Depending on your setup, you could have your workers send a "job complete" message. This way you can keep track, how many parts of your job are already finished (and also optionally which ones) by checking if the completed event was sent. You can then store this info in a less ephemeral format, e.g. in a jobs-table in your database that keeps track of how many "tasks" are sent out and completed for a job in a consumer for the completed event.

Comment: What about using websockets rather than constantly polling?